# Riemann Metric of $\mathcal M_1\cup\mathcal M_2$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, metric-geometry

Suppose $\mathcal M_{1},\ \mathcal{M}_{2}$ are $(n-1)$-manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^n$. $d_i$ is the geodesic distance defined on $\mathcal M_i$.

What is the name of the distance and metric defined by: $d(p_1,p_2)=\inf \{d_1(p_1,p)+d_2(p_2,p)|p\in\mathcal M_1\cap\mathcal M_2\}$?

What are some of the interesting properties of this metric? I learnt the metric of the product manifold $\mathcal M_1\times\mathcal M_2$ but they are not the same thing. Are there any connection of them?

Comment: Since the resulting space is not a manifold, this question is more naturally posed simply for metric spaces. You can view this as the quotient metric space of $\mathcal M_1 \sqcup \mathcal M_2$ under the equivalence relation that identifies the two copies of $\mathcal M_1 \cap \mathcal M_2;$ I'm not sure if there's a standard name for this.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I guess we could construct a function $f:\mathcal M_1\times\mathcal M_2\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(p1,p2)=d(p1,p2)$ and $f$ is geodesic convex.